# How do patches work in Git?

Tags: git, patch

I'm new to Git, but familiar with SVN. As a test I made a repository in a local directory with `git init`. Then I cloned the empty repository (over SSH using 127.0.0.1, which is another thing I wanted to test) to another local directory. I added some files in repository 2, I did `git add *` and finally `git commit -a -m "First source code"`.

I now want to create a patch using `git format-patch` and apply it on repository 1. How do I do this? I know there's a manual, but these things are terribly complicated and make me wanna do certain things to my monitor.

Comment: You don't need to use patches nearly as often if you're using Git, check out my answer below

Comment: [This](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/) article might be helpful understanding the complete process of patching

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create your patch via:

```
$ git format-patch master --stdout > patch.diff
```

then patch.diff will contain the diff, which you can then send to someone else to apply using:

```
$ git am < patch.diff
```

Sometimes, when the manuals are a little dense, it makes sense to look for a tutorial:

http://luhman.org/blog/2009/09/22/git-patch-tutorial

Comment: I got this error when apply patch "fatal: previous rebase directory .git/rebase-apply still exists but mbox given."

Answer (score 14):

The easiest method to create patches from the last commit (or last few commits) is to use `format-patch` with a negative number indicating the number of commits to create patches for:

```
git format-patch -1
```

You'll get a patch file named after the commit description. The use `am` to insert it into another repository:

```
git am << name_of_patch_file
```

Comment: Just a nitpick; but it's not a negative number, its just a flag to indicate the depth. No weird magicks going on! You can also specify a range of commits if that's more natural, e.g. `git format-patch origin/master..` or so on (see the git rev-parse manual for all the ways to express those arguments).

Comment: On Windows use `git am name_of_patch_file`

Answer (score 2):

Using GitHub patch

1. Add `.patch` to a commit URL to get the patch file, example

   [`github.com/git/git/commit/b6b3b6a.patch`](http://github.com/git/git/commit/b6b3b6a.patch)
2. Patch the original file like this:

   ```
   git am /tmp/b6b3b6a.patch
   ```

Using GitHub diff

1. Add `.diff` to a commit URL to get the patch file, example

   [`github.com/git/git/commit/b6b3b6a.diff`](http://github.com/git/git/commit/b6b3b6a.diff)
2. Patch the original file like this:

   ```
   git apply -p0 /tmp/b6b3b6a.diff
   ```

[§5.3 Distributed Git - Maintaining a Project](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Maintaining-a-Project)

Comment: Nice with an example, but the link unfortunately is not working anymore. :(

Answer (score 2):

The proper and easier way to do this if you're using Git is via remotes:

```
cd \path\to\repo1
git remote add otherrepo \path\to\repo2
git fetch otherrepo

git log otherrepo/master  ## Find the commit you want to steal in the list

git cherry-pick SOME_SHA1  ## Snag just one commit
git merge otherrepo/master  ## Merge all of the new commits from otherrepo/master
```

This will migrate *commits* from one repo to another, including their authors and commit messages, and will help you sort out merge conflicts (especially if you're moving > 1 commit)

Comment: Will this work when his initial repo is not the same? All the commits will have different hashes, since it has different history. Isn't patching the only way to do it then?

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) evolves to better use the branch description ("`git branch --edit-description`") as subject.

See [commit bf8e65b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf8e65b30b77308710f14d523782f99a4a23eb55), [commit a92331d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a92331df18112199d6aa7bee132ecf928509621c), [commit 46273df](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46273df7bfdd43e5f8a190d0a80a078ca55ce5ff) (15 Oct 2019) by [Denton Liu (`Denton-L`)](https://github.com/Denton-L).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b75ba9b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b75ba9bbd13877ff3351e150d3d053baec81f0db), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf8e65b30b77308710f14d523782f99a4a23eb55): teach `--cover-from-description` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Denton Liu</sup>

> Before, when `format-patch` generated a cover letter, only the body would be populated with a branch's description while the subject would be populated with placeholder text.
>
> However, users may want to have the subject of their cover letter automatically populated in the same way.
>
> Teach `format-patch` to accept the `--cover-from-description` option and corresponding `format.coverFromDescription` config, allowing users to populate different parts of the cover letter (**including the subject now**).

The [`git config` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bf8e65b30b77308710f14d523782f99a4a23eb55/Documentation/config/format.txt#L39-L43) now includes:

> ### `format.coverFromDescription`:
>
> The default mode for format-patch to determine which parts of     the cover letter will be populated using the branch's description.

And [`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bf8e65b30b77308710f14d523782f99a4a23eb55/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt#L175-L193):

> ### `--cover-from-description=<mode>`:
>
> Controls which parts of the cover letter will be automatically populated using the branch's description.
>
> - If `<mode>` is `message` or `default`, the cover letter subject will be populated with placeholder text.
>   The body of the cover letter will be populated with the branch's description. This is the default mode when no configuration nor command line option is specified.
> - If `<mode>` is `subject`, the first paragraph of the branch description will populate the cover letter subject.
>   The remainder of the description will populate the body of the cover letter.
> - If `<mode>` is `auto`, if the first paragraph of the branch description is greater than 100 bytes, then the mode will be `message`, otherwise `subject` will be used.
> - If `<mode>` is `none`, both the cover letter subject and body will be populated with placeholder text.

---

On the cover letter itself, Git 2.37 (Q3 2022) explains:

See [commit 4ec5008](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ec50080621f1072a51351cb0f93d1af15a3c531), [commit c2cd4b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2cd4b592f89c4d11570c815f80b1a45266e4939), [commit e97d474](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e97d474c7a7ba5c5ed0cfa56e100a9b22feb69ff), [commit afc8c92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afc8c92535749136e015ed8474b0db5613ad177d), [commit 489ef3b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/489ef3ba57e4114c0e6c98cc71a038fdefa92527) (12 May 2022) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3ce9483](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3ce9483c1a59277b73fe713504d44cf30d218b43), 25 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`MyFirstContribution`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afc8c92535749136e015ed8474b0db5613ad177d): add standalone section on cover letter
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> An explanation of the purpose of the cover letter is included in the "Sending Patches with [`git send-email`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/afc8c92535749136e015ed8474b0db5613ad177d/Documentation/git-send-email.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email))</sup> / `Preparing Email` section but is missing from the `Sending Patches via GitGitGadget` section.
>
> Add a standalone section "The cover letter" under the "Getting Started: Anatomy of a Patch Series" header to explain what the cover letter is used for and to draft the cover letter of the '`psuh`' topic used in the tutorial.

Note: `psuh` comes from:

> In this tutorial, we will add a new command, +**`git psuh`**+, short for "**`Pony Saying 'Um, Hello`**" - a feature which has gone unimplemented despite a high frequency of invocation during users' typical daily workflow.

`MyFirstContribution` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/afc8c92535749136e015ed8474b0db5613ad177d/Documentation/MyFirstContribution.txt#L763-L808):

> Subsequent iterations of the patch series are labelled "`PATCH v2`", "`PATCH v3`", etc. in place of "`PATCH`".
> For example, "`[PATCH v2 1/3]`" would be the first of
> three patches in the second iteration.
>
> Each iteration is sent with a new cover
> letter (like "`[PATCH v2 0/3]`" above), itself a reply to the cover letter of the previous iteration (more on that below).
>
> NOTE: A single-patch topic is sent with "`[PATCH]`", "`[PATCH v2]`", etc. without `i/n` numbering (in the above thread overview, no single-patch topic appears, though).
>
> ### The cover letter
>
> In addition to an email per patch, the Git community also expects your patches
> to come with a cover letter. This is an important component of change
> submission as it explains to the community from a high level what you're trying
> to do, and why, in a way that's more apparent than just looking at your
> patches.
>
> The title of your cover letter should be something which succinctly covers the
> purpose of your entire topic branch. It's often in the imperative mood, just
> like our commit message titles. Here is how we'll title our series:
>
> ---
>
> ### Add the 'psuh' command
>
> The body of the cover letter is used to give additional context to reviewers.
> Be sure to explain anything your patches don't make clear on their own, but
> remember that since the cover letter is not recorded in the commit history,
> anything that might be useful to future readers of the repository's history
> should also be in your commit messages.
>
> Here's an example body for `psuh`:
>
> ---
>
> Our internal metrics indicate widespread interest in the command
> `git-psuh` - that is, many users are trying to use it, but finding it is
> unavailable, using some unknown workaround instead.
>
> The following handful of patches add the `psuh` command and implement some
> handy features on top of it.
>
> This patchset is part of the `MyFirstContribution` tutorial and should not
> be merged.
>
> ---

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to "repository 2", the one you want to create the patch from, and run git-format-patch to create the patch : 
git format-patch master --stdout > name_of_patch_file

Then you go in "repository 1", the one you want to apply the patch to : 
git apply name_of_patch_file

Sometimes it is useful to just check if the patch will cause problems : 
git apply --check name_of_patch_file