# github gem code with pull request included

Tags: github, rubygems, pull-request

I am looking into one of these ruby gems at github. One of the features I really needed is supplied as a pull request, but unfortunately never merged to the main branch for some reason.

What would be the ideal way for me to pull this particular gem with the pull request included?

I would hate to pull the original gem code first and manually apply all the changes that are in the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to one of the commits, then add `.patch` to the URL. This will give you a nice patch file which you can apply with

```
git am 4f800.patch
```

- [github.com/freexploit/bootstrap/commit/4f800.patch](http://github.com/freexploit/bootstrap/commit/4f800.patch)
- [stackoverflow.com/a/9256253](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256253)